# determine client identity in mTLS gRPC server

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go, proto3, mtls

I am writing a mTLS gRPC server in Golang. Peers can be uniquely identified via *Common Name* of their certificate. My question is how can I access the client certificate, client certificate subject or client certificate common name in the implementation of gRPC message interface?

**Here is more context:**

Let's assume that there is only one service `NameService` and one method called `Add`. So my *.proto* file will contain the following (using proto3 syntax):

```
service NameService {
    rpc Add(Name) returns (Empty) {}
}

message Name {
    string name = 1;
}

message Empty {
}
```

Then I'll have to implement the following interface in go:

```
type NameServiceServer interface {
    Add(context.Context, *Name) (*Empty, error)
}
```

In the implementation of the method `Add`, I'd like to read the peer certificate. How can I do so?

P.S. I am just getting started with Golang so apologies if there is an obvious answer that I have missed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307385/11810946) help? (just change `.Subject` to  `.Subject.CommonName`).

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you, @Brits!